# Field Name stored in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to do this?

```
DECLARE @TableName As varchar(50)
set @TableName = 'tbl_goccurrence'   
DECLARE @OccurrenceFileNo As varchar(50)
    exec ('select ' + @OccurrenceFileNo + ' = occurrencefileno from @TableName where id=902000000001387589')
    print @OccurrenceFileNo
```

The error I get is: Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: what does the generated query string look like? what's in `@OccurenceFileNo`?

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic for any reason? What's the bigger picture you want to perform?

Comment: @JBond, the query is constructed at runtime i.e. dynamically.

Comment: @Marc B, OccurrenceFileNo is a String e.g. 'abcdefg'

Comment: then you'd have to quote it, otherwise `abcdefg` would be seen as a field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp_executesql` with an output parameter to assign the value to `@occurrenceFileNo`.

```
DECLARE @OccurrenceFileNo As varchar(50)
exec sp_executesql N'select @OccurrenceFileNo = occurrencefileno from tbl_goccurrence where id=902000000001387589', N'@OccurrenceFileNo varchar(50) out', @occurrenceFileNo out
print @OccurrenceFileNo
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  I am just testing this now.  It looks like it is what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

{starting over based on updated question}

I think you want:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select @OccurrenceFileNo = occurrencefileno from ' 
                 +  @TableName 
                 + ' where id=902000000001387589'
                  , N'@OccurrenceFileNo varchar(50) out'
                  , @occurrenceFileNo out
```

Comment: Thanks, but the error I get with your statement is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: What is the value of `@OccurrenceFileNo`?  Does it include spaces or other non-alphanumeric data? Is it the name of a field in the table you're querying?

Comment: Thanks again.  I am trying to pass the value returned by the query (OccurrenceFileNo) into the @OccurrenceFileNo variable.  OccurrenceFileNo is a string e.g. 123a, 123b etc.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I have edited the question to explain why the dynamic SQL is needed.  Please take a look again at the question in one minute.  Thanks again.